# Why when I use setDisplayName(), the result is null sometimes and sometimes not?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to setDisplayName() when creating user to use getDisplayName() to set it in my firebase database.
Here's my github : https://github.com/4dasqaw/GrowthWatcher

ProfilActivity :

```
public class ProfilActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private static final int UPDATE_USERNAME = 30;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private TextView mUsername;
    private EditText mNewUsername;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private Button mButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profil);

        mUsername = findViewById(R.id.profile_tv_username);
        mNewUsername = findViewById(R.id.profile_et_username);
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.profile_progressbar);
        mButton = findViewById(R.id.profile_change_username_btn);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        this.updateUIWhenCreating();

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                updateUsernameInFirebase();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateUIWhenCreating(){

        if (this.getCurrentUser() != null){
            String username = TextUtils.isEmpty(this.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()) ? getString(R.string.info_no_username_found) : this.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
            this.mUsername.setText(username); //Username is correct here
        }
        UserHelper.getUser(this.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                User currentUser = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
                String username = TextUtils.isEmpty(currentUser.getUsername()) ? getString(R.string.info_no_username_found) : currentUser.getUsername(); //don't work, username is empty because currentUser is null
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateUsernameInFirebase(){

        String username = this.mNewUsername.getText().toString();

        if (this.getCurrentUser() != null){
            if (!username.isEmpty() &&  !username.equals(getString(R.string.info_no_username_found))){
                UserHelper.updateUsername(username, this.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addOnFailureListener(this.onFailureListener()).addOnSuccessListener(this.updateUIAfterRESTRequestsCompleted(UPDATE_USERNAME));
            }
        }
    }

    private OnSuccessListener<Void> updateUIAfterRESTRequestsCompleted(final int origin){
        return new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                switch (origin){
                    // 8 - Hiding Progress bar after request completed
                    case UPDATE_USERNAME:
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
    }


}
```

My MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private final static int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private TextView mMail, mId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMail = findViewById(R.id.main_mail);
        mId = findViewById(R.id.main_id);

  @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        String vEmail = this.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        String vId = this.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName(); //show nothing
        mMail.setText(vEmail);
        mId.setText(vId);
    }

}
```

My UserHelp class :

```
package fr.tom_d.growthwatcher.api;

public class UserHelper {

    private static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "users";

    public static CollectionReference getUsersCollection() {
        return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(COLLECTION_NAME);
    }

    public static Task<Void> createUser(String uid, String username) {
        User userToCreate = new User(uid, username);
        return UserHelper.getUsersCollection().document(uid).set(userToCreate);
    }

    public static Task<DocumentSnapshot> getUser(String uid) {
        return UserHelper.getUsersCollection().document(uid).get();
    }

    public static Task<Void> updateUsername(String username, String uid) {
        return UserHelper.getUsersCollection().document(uid).update("username", username);
    }
}
```

My BaseActivity abstract class :

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected FirebaseUser getCurrentUser(){ return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); }

    protected void handleResponseAfterSignIn(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                this.createUserInFirestore();
            } else {
            }
        }
    }

    protected void createUserInFirestore(){

        if (this.getCurrentUser() != null){

            String username = this.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
            String uid = this.getCurrentUser().getUid();

            UserHelper.createUser(uid, username).addOnFailureListener(this.onFailureListener());
        }
    }
}
```

My updateUser() method resolve the problem but I don't understand why my createUser() not ...
Also mUsername in ProfilActivity get the correct username else if it's not the case of the database (without call updateUser()) but not vId in MainActivity.
I don't understand where's my fault, can someone explain me please ?

Comment: That's a lot of code for one question, please add only the most important parts of the code, relevant to your issue. It increases readability of the question.

Comment: I try to minimize the code with only the essential. But I put all thoses activites because I want to understand how getDisplayName() can give me different answer for the same uid....
Say me if I must minimize more

Comment: Just add those parts of the code where you're not getting the desired result, and the code for the method that is creating the problem.

Comment: I edit my question and add comment
I put my 2 activities where I want to show the username by using getDisplayName() method
After I put the class with the method to make query on the database and one abstract class used in my 2 activities.

Comment: Try to modify a little my registerActivity by adding a vPseudo which take `mPseudo.getText().toString()` in my `mPseudo.addTextChangedListener` method and use vPseudo in `UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                            .setDisplayName(vPseudo).build();`
But it's worse, I got an Authentification failed but my collection users is created in database and I got the user in my firebase authentification console....